# Changing checkbox from tick to cross in Preview app

Tags: macos, preview

When I check a checkbox it uses a tick but I want to use a cross. Is there any way to change this?

[image]

The one up, I needed to draw myself. If I leave it to Preview it chooses the tick. Is there anyway to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Preview inserts a check mark and I’ve not found any way to change this.

If the check box is correctly presented as an interactive element in the PDF, it can be set to use an X-mark, but this is to be defined in the PDF itself. (Then there’s sometimes a bug where both are inserted: [Strange tick mark in Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243476/37797).)

Comment: Is this a PDF document form and not even the preview app gui?

Comment: @bmike There’s nowhere in the Preview app GUI that uses such checkboxes. OP is perfectly describing the annotation behaviour of Preview when clicking in a square on a PDF.

Comment: Umm, open preferences window, select PDF tab  - lots of checks there in the gui and some radio buttons. .

Comment: @bmike Those are fancy colourful squares for checkboxes that look like the rest of macOS!

Comment: @bmike It is a checkbox in a PDF that contains a form